# asp:CreateUserWizardStep - The name 'UserName' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have TextBox inside `<asp:CreateUserWizard \>  -->  <WizardSteps>     -->   <asp:CreateUserWizardStep\>     -->     <ContentTemplate>`

this TextBox ID is UserName.

I'm facing a problem to push into this TextBox. when i do `UserName.Text = "some name";`

i get this error : **"The name 'UserName' does not exist in the current context"**

any help?

thankes

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["VolunteerSessionList"] != null) // test if exists
        {

           UserName.Text = "some name";


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just assuming that ASPX will be like the following. If so, you can access `UserName` textbox like - `RegisterUser.UserName = "test"`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Session["VolunteerSessionList"] != null)
   {
      RegisterUser.UserName = "test";
   }
}

<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="RegisterUser" runat="server" ...>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        ....
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="RegisterUserWizardStep" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                 ....
                 <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" />
                 ....
            </ContentTemplate>
            <CustomNavigationTemplate>
            </CustomNavigationTemplate>
        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```